# How to prove that a certain number is the supremum of a sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

I was trying to find the sum of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {n} {(n+1)!}$$ I have found and proved by induction that a formula for the $k^{th}$ partial sum is $$S_k=\sum_{n=1}^k \frac {n} {(n+1)!}=\frac {(k+1)!-1} {(k+1)!}$$

I know that the sequence $S_1,S_2,S_3,\dots$ is an increasing sequence and I believe that the supremum of this sequence is $1$. So, I want to use the theorem that every monotone bounded sequence converges to its supremum to conclude that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {n} {(n+1)!}=1$$

But I am having trouble showing that $1$ is the supremum of this sequence. Could someone please assist me in proving that the supremum of this sequence is $1$?

Comment: Each partial sum is less than $1$ because the numerator is less than the denominator.  As $k$ gets large the sum gets very close to $1$.

Comment: $$\frac{(k+1)!-1}{(k+1)!}=1-\frac{1}{(k+1)!}$$ which obviously converges to $1$. If this isn't clear, then I suggest you look over the concept of limits again untill you really get the hang of things.

Comment: @C-RAM Thanks, don't know why I didn't think of dividing up the fraction!

Comment: Don't feel too bad about missing this. I've made dumber mistakes in the past.

Comment: BTW for every $x\in [0,1$] there is a unique sequence $(a_{x,n})_{2\le n\in\Bbb N}$ such that each $a_{x,n}\in\Bbb N_0$ with $0\le a_{x,n}\le n-1$ and such that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac {a_{x,n}}{n!}=x.$